# Flashing candle light

Tags: animation, lighting

What is a simple way to simulate flashing candle / torch / fire light?
I'm not asking about animating the flames, I'm only interested in the light surrounding the fire, similar to what this device does: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPsVr4pU8Tg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double nexLightIntensity(lastIntensity)
    return clamp(0,1, lastIntensity+(rand()-.3)/100)
```

adjust parameters as needed

Comment: In addition to varying the light intensity, you may also want to move the light source slightly around its nominal location to make it flicker more realistically.

Comment: I would think using Perlin noise for the position and intensity might work well.

Comment: This works perfectly! I thought it would be harder :)